# Object is possibly undefined react typescript in the dropdown component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, typescript2.0

I am creating a dropdown component but typescript throws several errors on the options.map and selectedOption.title cases:

```
import React, { useRef,useState, useEffect } from "react";
import useToggle from '../hooks/useToggle';
import  useDetectOutsideClick  from '../hooks/useOutsideClick';

import "./select.scss";
interface TProduct {
    title?: string;
    options?: [];
    getDropDownValue?: any;
  }

  interface TOption {
    title?: string;
    value?: string;
    id?: any;
  }

const Select = (props: TProduct) => {
    let { title, options, getDropDownValue } = props;
    const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
    const [visibility, setVisibility] =  useDetectOutsideClick(dropdownRef, false);
      const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<TOption>({});
  
      return (
          
              <div
          className="base-select"
          ref={dropdownRef}
                  onClick={e =>  {
                      setVisibility(!visibility);
                  
                  }}
              >
                  <div className="selected-option">
                      <span
                          title={
                              selectedOption === ""
                                  ? title
                                  : selectedOption.title
                          }
                      >
                          {selectedOption === ""
                              ? title
                              : selectedOption.title.length <= 20
                              ? selectedOption.title
                              : selectedOption && selectedOption.title  && `${selectedOption.title.slice(0, 20)}`}
                      </span>
                      
                  </div>
                  {visibility && (
                      <div className="options">
                          <ul>
                      
                              {options
                                  .map((option) => (
                                      <li
                                          key={index}
                                          className={
                                             selectedOption && selectedOption ===       option
                                                  ? "active-option"
                                                  : ''
                                          }
                                          onClick={() => {
                        setSelectedOption(option);
                        getDropDownValue(option);
                       
                      }
                                          }
                                      >
                                          {option.title}
                                      </li>
                                  ))}
                          </ul>
                      </div>
                  )}
              </div>
      );
     };

    export default Select
```

So both looping of the list items and the titles are throwing error for options type and selectedOptions.title type **Object is possibly undefined**

What is wrong and how can be it fixed?

Comment: add a `?` to check for the availability of the object before accessing the property. such as `possiblyUndefinedObject?.title`

Comment: I also suggest updating the `&&` operator to `selectedOption?.id ===  option.id`, u can't possibly match an object such as `selectedOption` to another using the `==` or `===`.

Comment: @SultanH. it shows the error in key= {index} as well as in option.title in the loop. I guess ? marks are not solving the problem. If it's possible can you please answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixable by safe typing your `option` and `selectedOption` with the `?` operator from TS, and adding `index` to your `options.map` callback function.

```
<div
    className="base-select"
    ref={dropdownRef}
    onClick={e =>  {
      setVisibility(!visibility);
    }}
  >
    <div className="selected-option">
      <span
        title={
          selectedOption === ""
            ? title
            : selectedOption?.title
        }
      >
        {selectedOption === ""
          ? title
          : selectedOption?.title?.length <= 20
            ? selectedOption?.title
            : selectedOption?.title && `${selectedOption?.title?.slice(0, 20)}`}
      </span>

    </div>
    {visibility && (
      <div className="options">
        <ul>
          {options
            .map((option, index) => (
              <li
                key={index}
                className={
                  selectedOption?.id === option?.id
                    ? "active-option"
                    : ""
                }
                onClick={() => {
                  setSelectedOption(option);
                  getDropDownValue(option);
                }}
              >
                {option?.title}
              </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
```

I strongly suggest strictly typing the props of any react component that you are creating, TS is most usable here.

for instance:

```
type CustomSelectProps = {
  options?: Array<TOption>;
  title?: string;
  getDropDownValue?: (option: TOption) => void;
}
const Select: React.FC<CustomSelectProps> = (props) => {
  // ...component content...
}
```

Comment: It still shows error for 
       <span
          title={
            selectedOption === ""
              ? title
              : selectedOption?.title
          }
        >
          {selectedOption === ""
            ? title
            : selectedOption?.title.length <= 20
              ? selectedOption?.title
              : selectedOption?.title && `${selectedOption?.title.slice(0, 20)}`}
        </span>

Comment: Updated, @NewTechLover just apply the same concept there.. since `selectedOption` is possibly `undefined`, in that case the title itself would be, thus, we would be doing sth like `undefined.slice` which isn't possible there.